# Magento 2 How can I create two different sections under the same tab item in admin menu?

Tags: magento2, module, menu, system.xml, acl

I have created two different modules, now I want to create one tab in admin system configuration and show both modules configurations in different tabs.

I have two different modules within same "namespace". i.e. "Mymodule_First" and "Mymodule_Second". both have different functionality.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: can you update your code what you have tried with detail, it will help to others to give solutions?

Comment: @Utsav Gupta are you getting solution or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check your code or follow below steps.

- you need create `system.xml` for both modules
- use same tab id for both sections
- use same/different section id for both groups
- use unique group id for two tabs

**app/code/vendor/ModuleA/etc/adminhtml/system.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="custom" translate="label" sortOrder="10">
            <label>Custom Tab</label>
        </tab>
    <section id="firstmenu" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="150" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>First Menu</label>
            <tab>custom</tab>
            <resource>Vendor_ModuleA::index</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>General</label>
                <field id="moduleA_key" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>ModuleA Key</label>
                    <comment><![CDATA[Enter your comments]]></comment>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

**app/code/vendor/ModuleB/etc/adminhtml/system.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
    <section id="secondmenu" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="150" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Second Menu</label>
            <tab>custom</tab>
            <resource>Vendor_ModuleB::index</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>General</label>
                <field id="moduleB_key" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>ModuleB Key</label>
                    <comment><![CDATA[Enter your comments]]></comment>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

**Output:**

```
 --------------
    Custom Tab  ^|
    --------------
    First Menu   |
    -------------
    Second Menu  |
```

**Type 2:**

**app/code/vendor/ModuleA/etc/adminhtml/system.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="custom" translate="label" sortOrder="10">
            <label>Custom Tab</label>
        </tab>
    <section id="firstmenu" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="150" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>First Menu</label>
            <tab>custom</tab>
            <resource>Vendor_ModuleA::index</resource>
            <group id="taba" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Tab 1</label>
                <field id="moduleA_key" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>ModuleA Key</label>
                    <comment><![CDATA[Enter your comments]]></comment>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

**app/code/vendor/ModuleB/etc/adminhtml/system.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
    <section id="firstmenu" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="150" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <tab>custom</tab>
            <resource>Vendor_ModuleB::index</resource>
            <group id="tabb" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Tab 2</label>
                <field id="moduleB_key" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>ModuleB Key</label>
                    <comment><![CDATA[Enter your comments]]></comment>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

**Output:**

```
----------------------------------------------
Custom Tab  ^|   Tab 1                      ^
----------------------------------------------
First Menu   |   Tab 2                      ^
--------------
```

I hope it will help to achieve your goal

happy coding!

Comment: do we need to remove the "<tab id="custom" translate="label" sortOrder="10">
            <label>Custom Tab</label>
        </tab>" from second module's system.xml?

Comment: yes if already id defined

Comment: I have two different modules within same "namespace". i.e. "Mymodule_First" and "Mymodule_Second". both have different functionality.

Comment: I have drafted 2 type of outputs right? which type of output you expect?

Comment: I want to use type 1.

Comment: share your XML's

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87451/discussion-between-utsav-gupta-and-sathish).